# Canvas-lms - submitting an answer via API

Tags: canvas-lms

How do I submit an answer to a quiz by API? I believe can be done via https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/quiz_submissions.html - `POST /api/v1/courses/:course_id/quizzes/:quiz_id/submissions`, but how to I actually provide the answer to that request? There's no parameter in it which looks like it's what I'm looking for. Or maybe I have to use another end point?

Answer (score 0):

The API endpoint you need is [this](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/quiz_submission_questions.html#method.quizzes/quiz_submission_questions.answer) one. 
You will need to create an answer json object depending on the "question type" of the question you're trying to answer (see [this](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/quiz_submission_questions.html#Question+Answer+Formats-appendix) appendix)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your answer. You should try and expand upon your links by [editing your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33639091/edit). Some day in the future those links may be dead, and then suddenly this answer won't be able to help anyone. You should do your best to quote the relevant information from the links, as long as you're attributing the source of your information to the link!